# Get the text of multipart Gmail messages

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to fetch emails from Gmail by PHP using imap. I'm getting emails perfectly but my problem is that some of the messages are in a multipart format, and I would like to remove the multipart format.

For example, one Gmail message is "Hi, how are you? I am fine", but the message has text like this:

```
"Hi, how are you? I am fine


------=_NextPart_000_000B_01CE5613.4A5D9F20 // multipart format
Content-Type: text/html; // multipart format
    charset="us-ascii" // multipart format
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable". // multipart format
```

Comment: here below my code:                                                                 save_attachment(imap_fetchbody($imap,$result,"1.2"),$savefilename,$savefilepath,$savethumbpath);
imap_fetchbody($imap,$result,"1.2"); //This marks message as read

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this,

```
 $mailNumber = '11796';

$result =  $mailbox->getMessageContent($mailNumber);

if ($result->textHtml) 
  echo '<br>'.$result->textHtml;
else
  echo '<br>'.$result->textPlain;
```

Comment: i can't understand your code anand... can you please change this code into my code... because you used $mailbox variable.. i don't understand why you are using that...

Comment: here in this code i used ImapMailbox PHP-class. $mailbox is used to call the instenses.`public function getMessageContent($mId) {
  $struct = $this->imap_fetchstructure($this->mbox, $mId, FT_UID);

  $mail = new IncomingMail();
  $mail->mId = $mId;
  if(empty($struct->parts)) {
   $this->initMailPart($mail, $struct, 0);
  }
  else {
   foreach($struct->parts as $partNum => $partStruct) {
    $this->initMailPart($mail, $partStruct, $partNum + 1);
   }
  }
  return $mail;
  if ($mail->textPlain) return $mail->textPlain;
  else return $mail->textHtml;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
imap_fetchbody($imap,$result,"1.2");
```

to

```
imap_fetchbody($imap,$result,"1.1");
```

1.2 is TEXT/HTML email part, which is used for html email body.

1.1 is TEXT/PLAIN - plain text email body - for plain text messages you'll need to use this one.